# Unable to find $|F\to H|$

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

The above section is from the bondy's graph theory book and **I am having trouble checking the correctness of the equation (2.6) and (2.7).** The problem is for (2.6) the L.H.S. side (the summation side) I am getting 8 while for R.H.S side ($|F\to H|$) I am getting 4. Obviously  (8!=4). Also I am having trouble understanding how to compute (HcF) part (**in eqn 2.7 circled in red** )

[image]

I have tried to include the meaning of |F->H| as requested by adding an image section of its explanation from bondy's graph theory book but unfortunately even the book does a terrible job in my opinion in explaining this concept. I did clarify the meaning of |G->H|F and |G->H| from one very helpful user but **understanding what |F->H| means is something even I am having trouble with.**

[image]

For further clarification I included a section from the list of common graph parameters from the book where |G->H| means no. of embeddings in H but it doesn't say anything about |F->H| especially when the book talks about these concepts it took example of 3 graphs G,F,H where F was a subgraph of G.

[image]

The above pic showed the example graphs that I took to check eqn 2.6 and 2.7. So, summarizing **I want to understand the validity of eqn 2.6 and 2.7 preferabbly with a suitable example**

Comment: What is $|F -> H|$? I am not familiar with this notation and you never say explicitly what it is.

Comment: I have included the entire page where the book uses this notation. It does seem to explain what it is but does so terribly. So I had to take my guesses of what it meant and till now even I am unable to understand what it is. I mean if I could get what |F->H| meant it would have been easy to move forward. So you can say partly the motive of this question is to understand what |F->H| means.

Comment: Never mind I am new here, and for any users who are having trouble understanding my question, I am truly sorry and in future I will try my best to format my questions as best as possible(be it details wise, notation wise, and so on...) so that it is better understandable. As for this question  I will surely repost it on a seperate page in a more understandable format.

Comment: Don't worry too much about the question format, to me it's okay to understand what you need. I cannot answer myself because it is related to knowledge I do not know.

Comment: No problem,..sir.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah so I figured out the answer to this, and it was mostly trivial hence I feel stupid but |F->H| essentially meant the no. of embeddings of F in H but considering all the automorphisms of F. Say permutation of the vertex set yielded 3 different graphs from F i.e F1,F2,F3 then, and say we have x1,x2,x3 copies of them respectively, now when intersecting F1/F2/F3 with H we must get the graph itself. Now say F1 and F2 intersected with H have F1 and F2 itself we would consider the copies x1and x2, i.e. |F->H| would become x1+x2. This with my example |F->H| is indeed 8 and not 4.I have attached an image of my working in paper, for more clarification,

[image]

[image]